# NSIS CreateShortCut not display correct string in target field of short cut

Tags: powershell, nsis

The following is an excerpt of an NSIS installer.

My issue is when I execute:

```
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\PRESS_Survey_PS.lnk" $shortcutPath "" $INSTDIR\images\appIcons\Survey.ico
```

It produces this in the target field of the shortcut using the variable $shortcutPath:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command &.\PRESS_Survey.ps1"
```

The $shortcutPath variable is built using the following strcpy:

```
StrCpy $powerShellPath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "
StrCpy $shortcutPath $powerShellPath$\"&.\PRESS_Survey.ps1$\"
```

when I write out the $shortcutPath variable to my ps1 file using:

```
FileWrite $0 $powershellComment$shortcutPath$NewLine
```

It produces this:

```
#C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "&.\PRESS_Survey.ps1"
```

When I try to execute the shortcut using:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command &.\PRESS_Survey.ps1"
```

it fails, asking where the PRESS_Survey.ps1 is located.

When I replace the CreateShortCut version with the FileWrite version in the target field:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "&.\PRESS_Survey.ps1"
```

it runs.

Why is the value of $shortcutPath not the same in both instances?
Is this me doing something wrong or is this a windows shortcut issue?
In either case, is there a way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably two things going on here.

First off, the shortcut target and arguments are two different parameters so you need two variables:

```
StrCpy $powerShellPath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
StrCpy $parameters '-command "&.\PRESS_Survey.ps1"'
CreateShortcut "$DESKTOP\PRESS_Survey_PS.lnk" $powerShellPath $parameters "$INSTDIR\images\appIcons\Survey.ico"
```

The other problem is `.\` in the path, `.` means the current directory and I don't really recommend using it in a shortcut. If you insist then you need to keep in mind that the current/working directory stored in the shortcut comes from the path set with `SetOutPath` in NSIS so you might need to do something like this:

```
Push $OUTDIR ; Save the old path
StrCpy $powerShellPath "$SysDir\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
StrCpy $parameters '-command "&.\PRESS_Survey.ps1"'
SetOutPath "c:\path\where\PRESS_Survey\is\located" ; For .\ paths
CreateShortcut "$DESKTOP\PRESS_Survey_PS.lnk" $powerShellPath $parameters "$INSTDIR\images\appIcons\Survey.ico"
Pop $OUTDIR 
SetOutPath $OUTDIR ; Restore
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Concerning: "The other problem is .\ in the path, . means the current directory and I don't really recommend using it in a shortcut." We set the 'Start in' field of the shortcut to the directory we install to.

Comment: ...but you know what the full path is in the installer so you might as well just use the full path.